# How can use a filter in my AngularJS precisely on an ng-bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

I tried to use this simple filter :

```
App.filter('MyCutFilter', function ()
{
    return function(input)
    {
        return input.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    };
})
```

On a element of ng-repeat like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="jf in ctrl.Files" class="tablerow">
    <td><span ng-bind="jf.id"></span></td>
    <td><span class="filename" ng-bind="jf.FileName | MyCutFilter"></span></td>
```

But i got the following error :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CutFilterProvider <- CutFilter <- UpFileController

What can i do to correct it ?

Thanks for your help in adavance.

Comment: How do you use this filter? And `MyCutFilter` is not the same as `CutFilter` - you realize this, do you?

Comment: @dfsq Sorry I edited my question ^^

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr may be there is an error in dependency injection...

Comment: Did you include the filter file in your layout template?

Comment: @SwarnavaSarkar Thanks, i already checked it but i will recheck, we never know.

Comment: @TimB Yes it is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i created my own service like this :

```
'use strict';

App.factory('UtilsService', [function(nameTable){

    return {
               parseTheseNames: function ParseThesesNames(nameTable){
                    for (var i=0; i < nameTable.length; i++)
                    {
                        //console.log(d[i].upFileName); 
                        nameTable[i].upFileName = nameTable[i].upFileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                        //console.log("obj " + d[i].upFileName);
                    }
            }
    };

}]);
```

And i am using it like this :

```
App.controller('FileController',[..., 'UtilsService',...,
function(..., UtilsService, ...){
.
.
.

function(d){
    UtilsService.parseTheseNames(d);
    self.upFiles = d;
}
.
.
.
```

I changed what i wanted to get the return of the data directly from a callback to be able to parse the filename earlier.

Thanks for the help and the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error,

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CutFilterProvider <-
>   CutFilter <- UpFileController

It looks like you are trying to inject `Cutfilter` in a controller named `UpFileController`. Please, remove the `Cutfilter` injection from `UpFileController`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice.